# Passing main arguments to a second thread for freeglut launch

Tags: c++, pthreads, program-entry-point, glut, freeglut

I am new to OpenGL and Freeglut and am wanting to create a thread for the peripheral graphics output that is not the Operating system thread. When I create the second thread I want to pass the main command line arguments so I can initialise freeglut.

I am using:

Name : Code::Blocks, Version : 20.03-r11997, SDK Version : 2.0.0, Scintilla Version: 3.7.5, Compiler Name : GNU GCC Compiler.

OS Name : Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, OS Type : 64-bit, GNOME Version : 3.36.8, Windowing System : X11.

error:

> static assertion failed: std::thread: arguments must be invocable
> after conversion to rvalues

```
#include "Thread.h"
#include <thread>

#include <GL/glut.h>

class Thread
{
    public:
        Thread()
        {

        }
        ~Thread()
        {

        }
        static void run_Td_1(int argc, char *argv[])
        {
            glutInit(&argc, argv);
            glutInitWindowSize(640,480);
            glutInitWindowPosition(10,10);
            glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH);

            glutCreateWindow("GLUT Shapes");

            glutMainLoop();
        }

    protected:

    private:
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::thread td_1(Thread::run_Td_1, &argc, argv);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

How to I pass the arguments correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the ampersand character (`&`) from the argc argument:

```
std::thread td_1(Thread::run_Td_1, argc, argv);
```

`Thread::run_Td_1()` expects an integer for its first argument, not a pointer to an integer.

You can try to reproduce the error and experiment [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y7r9PShdMlmCrGaN).